# How does Flower determine if a Celery worker is online/offline?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, flower

Within celery, I see sometimes that the worker is offline. I run Flower in one Docker container and the Celery worker in another one. I use a RabbitMQ broker.

I see that the worker jumps between offline <-> online quite often.

What does it mean that a worker is offline? How does Flower figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worker is considered "offline" if it does not broadcast heartbeat signal for some (short) period of time.